# Scanning ports on non local hosts

Tags: java, network-programming, port-scanning

I am writing a port scanner in Java. I am using a for loop to count through ports from 0 to 100, constructing a socket on each and seeing if it throws an exception or not. However, when I try to scan non local ports such as on "www.google.com" It scans the first one and then stops (literally the program just waits), if anyone knows why this is I would like to know.
Here is the code for the Scan Method. Please note the variable ia is an InetAddress object

```
private void scan(int low, int high){
    for(int port =low; port<high; port++){
    try {
    connection = new Socket(ia, port);
    r.addPort(port);
    System.out.println("port "+port+" open");
    connection.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
    System.out.println("port "+port+" not open");
    }
}
}
```

Comment: That's how many systems defend themselves against port scanning. They discard your SYN packet without replying, so your scanner will wait forever (or until it times out) for a response that never comes. It's called a blackhole by the way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try to set a timeout on a socket. It will fail faster.

`connection.setSoTimeout(10*1000); // milliseconds`

Comment: you have to set it before you call a blocking operation.

Comment: create an empty socket, set the timeout, try to open it

Comment: Ok I just did what you say that times out the socket, but i've just tried scanning the ports on my friends computer on the same network using her IPAddress and I get the same problem. If I scan the ports on my local machine then it works perfectly well and doesn't freeze even if I dont set the timeout

Comment: What IP are you trying to scan? localhost? Localhost scanning is something totally different. Try your outer IP

Comment: I just scanned my outer IP address and it worked fine, just like it did when I was scanning 'localhost'

Comment: Does it freeze when you only "scan" one port that you know is open? (Check with telnet that it is indeed open if you're not sure.)

Comment: It freezes when it tries to connect to the second port number that it loops to. It does the first one fine